# How to access a method inside Kendo UI's filterable itemTemplate?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid in which one of the columns is filterable. However to ensure proper localization of the values in the filterable popup, I need to call a method within the itemTemplate , which will return the localized value of the data.

I have tried implementing this in a sample [DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/iCOMobeM) , it worked . However this doesn't work for my actual code. My code looks a little like this. The kendo grid is created inside the Marionette View. I can't really find the difference between the dojo and my code. In my case it gives an error that the method is not defined.
Any leads on this will be appreciated.

```
define(function(require) {

    var MarionetteView = Marionette.View.extend({
        init: function(){
        //init Variables
    },

    createGrid: function(){
        var kendoGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          columns: [ {
                field: "country",
              filterable: {
                    multi:true,
                  itemTemplate: function(e) {
                    //Test Method is not accessible here
                    return "<span><label><span>#= test(data.country|| data.all) #</span><input type='checkbox' name='" +                                                    e.field + "' value='#= data.country#'/></label></span>"
                    e.field + "' value='#= data.country#'/></label></span>"
                    }
                }
            }],
            filterable: true,
            dataSource: [ { country: "BG" }, { country: "USA" } ]
        });
        function test( text ){
            return text + 1;
        }

    }
    )};
    return MarionetteView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it works in your DOJO is because the function is created in the scope of the **Window**. Since the Grid is also created in the Window scope, you could access **test()** in the item template.

In  your case, your scope is changing to the Marionette view. So, if you would like to use test now, it will have to do something like this:

```
window.test = function(text){ //Your logic }
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks that works for me. Would love to upvote but can’t because of less reputation.